# Subset R data frame based on group-level values

Tags: r

I have a data frame (`df1`) with ID, date which is sorted in ascending order by (1) ID & (2) date:

```
ID____Date
1_____1990-01-01
1_____1991-01-01
1_____1992-01-01
1_____1993-01-01
2_____1990-01-01
2_____1991-01-01
3_____1990-01-01
3_____1991-01-01
3_____1992-01-01
```

I want to subset the above data frame based on group level values from the following data frame (`df2`):

```
ID____Date
1_____1993-01-01
2_____1990-01-01
3_____1991-01-01
```

Subsetting condition: Choose all rows of specific ID in `df1` for which date is less than or equal to (`<=`) the date for corresponding ID in `df2`.

In the above example the desired output is:

```
ID____Date
1_____1991-01-01
1_____1992-01-01
1_____1993-01-01
2_____1990-01-01
3_____1990-01-01
3_____1991-01-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), join with 'df2' `on` the 'ID' column, subset the rows where 'Date' is less than or equal to 'i.Date', and assign (`:=`) the 'i.Date' to NULL.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, on = 'ID'][Date <= i.Date][, i.Date := NULL]
```

---

Or this can be done in a single step

```
setDT(df1)[df2, .SD[Date <= i.Date], on = 'ID', by = .EACHI]
#   ID       Date
#1:  1 1990-01-01
#2:  1 1991-01-01
#3:  1 1992-01-01
#4:  1 1993-01-01
#5:  2 1990-01-01
#6:  3 1990-01-01
#7:  3 1991-01-01
```

Or

```
setDT(df1)[df2, .SD[Date <= i.Date] ,on = 'ID']
```

---

We can also do this using `base R`

```
df1[df1$Date <= df2$Date[match(df1$ID, df2$ID)],]
#  ID       Date
#1  1 1990-01-01
#2  1 1991-01-01
#3  1 1992-01-01
#4  1 1993-01-01
#5  2 1990-01-01
#7  3 1990-01-01
#8  3 1991-01-01
```

Comment: Base R solution works much faster than data.table and sqldf. Processed 2 million rows in 1 second compared to 20 seconds for sqldf and 2 seconds for data.table

Comment: @NaveenMathew  It is because instead of joining, we used `match` to get the index.  It is much quicker.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `sqldf` also :

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.* from df1 a, df2 b where a.Date <= b.Date AND a.ID = b.ID" )
```